# html to pdf conversion using javascript (jsPDF and html2canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I've been looking into converting an HTML page into a PDF on the client side. I found a method with Javascript using html2canvas to parse the DOM and calculate the styles applied, and jsPDF to create the PDF. Link to my page - http://www.choosenj.com/html-to-pdf/

I'm struggling with a couple issues I need resolved:

- The Canvased image is rendering the whole page as a single PDF, is there a way to split the long image into a multi page PDF?
- Currently panels load as you scroll down, is there a way to load the entire page when clicking the "Create PDF button"?
- If I wanted to canvas only panels that had a checkbox selected, how would I edit my JS?

Here my code below (Note: Most include html2canvas and jsPDF javascript libraries):

```js
// Html to PDF
$(window).load(function(){

    var
     form = $('#Content'),
     cache_width = form.width(),
     a4  =[ 850,  2000];  // for a4 size paper width and height

        $('#create_pdf').on('click',function(){
        $('body').scrollTop(0);
        createPDF();
    });

    //create pdf
    function createPDF(){
        getCanvas().then(function(canvas){
        var
        img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
        doc = new jsPDF({
              unit:'px',
              format:'a4'
            });
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 180,  630);
            doc.save('choosenj.pdf');
            form.width(cache_width);
        });
    }

    // create canvas object
    function getCanvas(){
         form.width(cache_width).css('max-width','none');
         return html2canvas(form,{
             imageTimeout:2000,
             removeContainer:true
        });
    }

}());
```

```html
<!-- #Content -->
<div id="Content">
    <div class="content_wrapper clearfix">

        <!-- .Main Content -->
        <div class="sections_group">

            <div class="entry-content" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">

                <div style="margin: 10px 0;"><a id="create_pdf" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-square vc_btn3-style-flat vc_btn3-color-green" style="margin:0 20px;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;font-family: 'FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond', Arial, sans-serif !important;text-transform: uppercase !important;">Create PDF</a>    </div>

                <?php
                    while ( have_posts() ){
                        the_post(); // Post Loop
                    }
                ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Contact Section-->
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('contact-us') ?>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated,

Chris G

Comment: did you try pdf.js? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js  or you could give this solution a whirl http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-ask-ben-print-part-of-a-web-page-with-jquery.htm

Comment: the ones suggested have multi-page options. if your code works, i don't see what the problem is

Comment: i just did, and as i said previously, the other options suggested provide multi-page options

Comment: Let me give it another look. Thanks

Comment: plus you have it set to a4